# sending multiple files laravel notifications

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send multiple attachments to a user by using laravel notifications, I can send now one file but my way is not a dynamic way , I tried to send the files by using foreach but it  sent only the first file

===========================

blade.php

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
   <input type="file" name="files[]" class="dropify" accept=".pdf,.jpg, .png, image/jpeg, image/png"
                                 />
 </div><br>
    
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <input type="file" name="files[]" class="dropify" accept=".pdf,.jpg, .png, image/jpeg, image/png"
                               />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <input type="file" name="files[]" class="dropify" accept=".pdf,.jpg, .png, image/jpeg, image/png"
                               />
   </div>
```

controller

```
 if ($request->hasfile('files')) {
    foreach ($request->file('files') as $file) {
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path('Attachments/' .), $name);
        $data[] = $name;
        $attachments = new TaskAttachment();
        $attachments->file_name = $name;
        $attachments->save();
    }
    //to send email
    Notification::route('mail', $engineer_email)
        ->notify(new AddTaskWithAttachments($data));
}
```

AddTaskWithAttachments.php [static way]

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
    ->subject(" new task")
    ->action('link', $url)
    ->attach(public_path('Attachments/'.$this->files[0]));
 }
```

with foreach

```
foreach($this->files as $file){
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(" new task")
        ->action('link', $url)
        ->attach(public_path('Attachments/'.$file));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return in the foreach prevents multiple executions.
You could try this, but I'm not sure it works, couldn't find it documented:

```
$mailmessage = (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(" new task")
        ->action('link', $url);

foreach($this->files as $file){
    $mailmessage->attach(public_path('Attachments/'.$file));
}

return $mailmessage;
```